# VueJS: change global state through chain of recursive components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I use recursive component to render nested array in Vue. Also I need to make possible to check any leaf of these tree, render every node as true/false/indeterminate (if some leafs are selected) and store all selected values in some ‘global’ variable. What’s the right way to pass the information and store the states? I think using a reference to the “root” component is not right and creating chain of events through all nested components may be too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect task for vuex.
It is the defacto store system into the vue ecosystem.

You store all of your data into that store and access and manipulate them with mutations and getters.

And you get the benefit, that everything in your Views stays synced.
Check out their amazing docu at: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Comment: Is it worth to add Vuex for only one task on one page?

Comment: I think so. Because as always: things grow... ;)

Comment: Just for an example: is it the proper way to do it without vuex?